# Javascript: How do you filter search results based on multiple values (regardless of the order that the words are typed)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React: How do you filter search results based on multiple values (regardless of order that the words are typed)
Example: I want to be able to search for the title of a document whether I type "phone repair process", "repair phone process", or "process phone repair".

(Currently the search only works if I don't skip words and they must be in order)
Note: I'm still learning React and I did try researching for this information on my own with no luck.

Below is my code:

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            documents: documents,
            searchField: '',
        }
    }

    onSearchChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({searchField: event.target.value})
    }

    render() {
        const filteredDocuments = this.state.documents.filter(documents => {
            return documents.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchField.toLowerCase())
        })
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 className='p-5 text-teal-800 text-xl'>Documentation</h1>

                <div className='p-5'>
                    <Searchbox searchChange={this.onSearchChange} />
                </div>

                <div>
                    <Button />
                </div>

                <div className='m-5 md:m-10 xl:m-20'>
                    <CardList documents={filteredDocuments} />
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Searchbox.js

```
import React from "react";

const Searchbox =({searchChange}) => {
        return (
            <input type="search"
            placeholder='Search Document Title...'
            className='bg-gray-100 rounded-md px-2 py-1 border border-gray-400 outline-none'
            onChange={searchChange}
            />
        )
    }

export default Searchbox;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's more of a javascript question than a React. the only part you actually need to edit is

```
const filteredDocuments = this.state.documents.filter(documents => {
return documents.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchField.toLowerCase())
```

try splitting the string into an array of words:

```
const words = this.state.searchField.toLowerCase().split(" ");
```

then use the `every` method on Boolean. which checks if a condition is met on every element.

```
const filteredDocuments = this.state.documents.filter(document => {
    return words.every(word => document.title.toLowerCase().includes(word))
})
```

you should note that this method searches the string word by word and does not care if the words are close to each other.

I suggest using specialized libraries like [Fuse.js](https://fusejs.io/) which provide an easy to use, yet powerful search APIs.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate the help! Very clear answer. Also, I will update my title to reflect that it should be a JavaScript rather than a react question.

Comment: @Asanyth Glad to hear it.

Comment: @Asanyth Glad to hear it.